# Run in parallel n-functions that share some variable

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, share, parfor

I have tried to run this simple code, but doesn't work, I can't pass the output of `func1` to `func2` to do further calculations. Obviously, `func1` and `func2` are only an example, in order to understand in a better way what I will do.

```
parfor i = 1:2
    if i == 1
      a = func1();
    else
      func2(a);
    end
end

 function a = func1()
     a = 3;
 end
 function o = func2(x)
    o = x + 2;   
 end
```

I get the following error if I run this:

```
An UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for 'a'.  This might be because the file containing
'a' is not accessible on the workers.  Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the required files
to be attached.  For more information see the documentation for 'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles'.

Caused by:
    Undefined function or variable 'a'.
```

How can I pass the output of `func1` in a `parfor` loop?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `parfor` executes the loop inherently in random order, to force you to make all calculations independent on others. Your code is **dependent**. You cannot run `i=2` before `i=1`, because the value of `a` is not set in that case (which is more or less what the lengthy and complicated error tells you). You have to make each and every loop iteration **independent** from all others in order to be able to parallelise it.

The main reason for this is that each worker would not see what the others are doing. If you require results from previous iterations in subsequent ones, there would not be much point in parallelising in the first place.

```
parfor ii=1:5
    disp(ii)
end
```

This would result in, e.g. `4 3 5 2 1`, or any other permutation. This happens because each core gets assigned *one* of the iterations, and spits out a result as soon as it is done.

Thus, for your "simple" example the solution would be to *first* calculate `a=func1()`, and then run a `parfor ii = 2:2`.

In general: recursive loops (i.e. a loop where any iteration depends on the outcome of a previous one, however far back) *cannot* be parallelised. Thus, write your code to be non-recursive.